# mysql wpdb query count returning null

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My wpdb query to mysql returning null where there should be one match.

### Below is my code

```
global $wpdb;
$popular = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta AS pm, $wpdb->woocommerce_order_items AS woo
    WHERE (woo.order_id = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_value = 142)
");
var_dump($popular);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're selecting multiple values in your query while get_var only expects a single value to be returned. Try using get_results instead.

Comment: Its returning empty array

Comment: Then the query itself is returning no results, have you tried running it directly on the database?

Comment: No.i have run `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_postmeta AS pm, wp_woocommerce_order_items AS woo WHERE (woo.order_id = pm.post_id AND pm.meta_value = 142)"` but returning error

Comment: Your query needs adjusting, you need to select the columns you want to use in your where clause rather than just the count.

Comment: Yes its returning 3 results `SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` as pm, `wp_woocommerce_order_items` as woo WHERE pm.post_id = woo.order_id AND pm.meta_value = 142`

Answer (score 0):

You can use join here

```
$popular = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta AS pm left join $wpdb->woocommerce_order_items AS woo on(woo.order_id = pm.post_id)  WHERE pm.meta_value = 142");
var_dump($popular);
```